# I am comparing the sex ratio of pheasants across Study Areas, (10), Release sites (26), and Years (13)

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, binary-data

I am using Binary Logistic Regression and comparing Models using AIC. The Model is: sex ratio= study area + release site + years  When I count the number of Parameters (K) in the Model -do I count Study Area, Release Site, and Years-each as 1 parameter.  All 3 are categorical variables with multiple levels. OR is it 10 for the Study Area, 26 for the Release Site, and 13 for the Years?????  10 different study areas-26 different release sites of pheasants (within those 10 study areas and data collected on sex ratio from 2006-2018.  Should I use YEAR as a covariate and continuous variable rather than a fixed factor and categorical variable?   How many Parameters (K)  for this Model and if YEAR is a covariate?

Please help me.

Thanks

Scott

Comment: What exactly is your model and where do the numbers 10, 26, and 13 come from?  Would those be the numbers of categories in each variable?  If so, then do you conceive of "years" as being a numerical date or as a nominal variable?

Comment: I have edited the question with the Model